# how to use namespace and oop concept in php

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I tried to access another method of class in another class like in oops based but i am unsuccessful to do that i am described my problem here
I Create a Name Spaces
Like the following Directory
  directory :Tets/test.php and its code like:

```
<?php
        namespace Test;
        final class TestClient
        {
            public static function GetStoryById($fb_user_id)
            {   
            $all_story=array();
            $query="select * from story where fb_user_id='".$fb_user_id."' order by story_id desc";
            $query_run=  mysql_query($query);
            echo mysql_error();
            $num_rows=  mysql_num_rows($query_run);
            if($num_rows>0)
                {
                $fb_user_id=$data['fb_user_id'];
                while($row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                {
                   $all_story['story_id']=$row['story_id'];
                   $all_story['fb_user_id']=$row['fb_user_id'];
                   $all_story['tagline']=$row['tagline'];
                   $all_story['experience']=$row['experience'];
                   $all_story['category_type']=$row['category_type'];
                   $all_story['lat']=$row['lat'];
                   $all_story['log']=$row['log'];
                   $all_story['datetime']=$row['datetime'];
                   $all_story['last_update_at']       =$row['last_update_at'];
                }
                }
                if(!empty($all_story['story_id']))
                {
                 $all['all_story']=$all_stories;
                 $all['statusmessage']="ok";
                 $all['statuscode']="1";
                }
                else{
                   $all['statusmessage']="there is no story found";   
                  $all['statuscode']="2";
                }
                $response['response']=  array_reverse($all);
                $deatils=json_encode($response);
             return $details;
            }
            }


I need to access its Function GetStoryById
in another php file which is like 
--get.php
and code like


<?php

define('Tets-SDK-DIR', './Tets');
use Test\TestClient;

class facebook_details {

     public function user_detail_with_story($data)
     {
       $query="select * from user where fb_user_id='".$data['fb_user_id']."'";
       $query_run=  mysql_query($query);
       $num_rows=  mysql_num_rows($query_run);
       if($num_rows>0)
       {
           $row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run);
           $status['user_details']=$row;
           $fb_user_id= $data['fb_user_id'];
         $status['all_details']=TestClient::GetStoryById($fb_user_id); 
       }
       echo json_encode($status);

     }  
}

$facebook_details=new facebook_details();

if($_REQUEST['action']=='user_detail_with_story')
{
    $facebook_details->user_detail_with_story($_REQUEST);
}
```

and when i try to access through url by providing action=user_detail_with_story&user_id=10 e.g 
i got the fetal error 
Fatal error: Class 'Test\TestClient' not found in... in line 16

Pl z help me how to use another class object in another class by any method so i does need to write method again and again

I will be waiting Response

Thanks

Comment: You will need to autoload your classes on initialisation of your PHP application. This can be achieved using for example the PSR-4 Class Loader convention and you could use the Symfony2 autoloader http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/psr4_class_loader.html

Answer (score 1):

i Resolved my problem just use this code `include './Test/Test.php';` above the code of this line 
 or in the before class 
 $status['all_details']=TestClient::GetStoryById($fb_user_id);

Comment: also u can try autoloader in php